# Should I use a constant for an object?

Tags: java, oop

I have a class `StrLinkedList` which is a linked list class with the values of strings.

I'm practising java by making a lotto game, so I have `winingNumbers`, `possibleNumbers`, and `prizes`. All 3 are instances of the `StrLinkedList` class. The `prizes` values will never change unless you change the code, but to add the values to this list you use `prizes.add(x)`.

I am wondering just for best practise sake, when I make this object as a global object, would there be any reason to or not to make it a constant? I was told that all variables should be constant unless they do need to change.

```
public static final StrLinkedList prizes = new StrLinkedList();
```

My thought is that because I'm changing the values in the object after defining it, it shouldn't be constant. But also as the object is not changing, just a property, it would be a constant. And as I am adding set values that will not change later in the program it would be constant.

Comment: You are mutating the object which is once assigned to a variable. `final` is fine.

Comment: If you're learning Java from C++ or something similar, `const` in C++ refers to the contents of the object, in Java `final` refers to the handle, the contents are mutable.

Comment: Also, in Java `static` just means that all objects of that class share the field. So `class A { static int i; int j };` means that for `A firstA = new A(); A secondA = new A();`, if you set `firstA.i = 2;` then `secondA.i` is also 2, but `firstA.j = 3;` does not change `secondA.j` (remains default 0).

Comment: "I am wondering just for best practise sake, when I make this object as a global object," best practice is _not_ to make it a global object.

Comment: If by *constant* you mean declaring `final` or `static final`, yes, that makes perfect sense to do, but as the answer says, beware that your object will still be mutable, can be changed (unless you coded your `StrLinkedList` class in a way to prevent it).

Answer (score 2):

As [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78169736/should-i-use-a-constant-for-an-object#comment137810470_78169736), regarding the use of the term “constant”, you seem to be conflating multiple concepts in Java.

In your code:

```
public static final StrLinkedList prizes = new StrLinkedList();
```

… your variable `prizes` holds not a list but a [*reference*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_(computer_science)) to a list.

By marking that variable as *final* you are saying that only one reference should be ever be assigned to that variable. As `final`, that variable can never be assigned another reference, nor can that variable ever be null (after construction). So, a `final` variable is not literally a “variable” because its value (the reference) never varies.

By marking that variable as `static`, you are saying that you want only a single variable per class, regardless of how many objects of that class are ever instantiated. So static variables are not object-oriented, they are a kind of [global variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_variable). As such, their use is generally discouraged.

You seem to be saying that your `StrLinkedList` class is a modifiable collection, able to add or remove elements.

The term [constant](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_(computer_programming)) has no precise definition in the context of Java. But I think most Java programmers would expect the term to mean a completely unchanging value. Specifically:

- `final`
- If an object, deeply [immutable](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object) in that the contents of the object never change
- If a collection, then (a) [unmodifiable](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#unmodifiable), and (b) populated by immutable objects.

Being static is an orthogonal issue, unrelated to being a constant.

Your example does not meet those conditions, so I would not call it a constant.

In Java, the convention is that a constant should be named in all uppercase.

The following is an example of a constant collection. The reference variable is marked `final`. The list returned by `List.of` is unmodifiable. The objects populating the list are fully immutable (`String` class is immutable).

```
final List < String > COLORS = List.of( "red" , "green" , "blue" ) ;
```

(In real work, I would define those colors as an [enum](https://www.baeldung.com/a-guide-to-java-enums), but that’s beside the point here.)

You said:

> to or not to make it a constant

You don’t “make” a variable be constant in Java. It either is or is not a constant depending on its declarations.

You asked:

> for best practise sake, when I make this object as a global object, would there be any reason to or not to make it a constant

Generally, in object-oriented products, the best practice is to avoid global variables as much as possible. In your example, a lotto game has a collection of prizes, so as a part of that class declare a member field for that collection. If you intend to never replace that collection, mark the member field as `final`. So no need for a `static`, no need for a global variable. Every instance of a lotto game has its own list of prizes.

```
class Lotto 
{
    final SequencedCollection < Prize > prizes = new StrLinkedList() ;
    …
}
```

By the way… Generally best to declare a collection variable as the most general of interfaces that meets the specific needs. As of Java 21, we have [`SequencedCollection`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/SequencedCollection.html) as the super-interface of the `List` interface. See [*JEP 431*](https://openjdk.org/jeps/431).

If you do find a need for a global variable, whether that variable should be a constant is a separate issue. Being global does not determine being constant.